# What is the difference between Low and High Advice?

Tags: rome-2-total-war

In both Total War: Attila and Total War: Rome II, what is the difference that Low and High Advice do for you? Is there a setting (or if it is Low) that just says important things, like your general dying etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

High advice essentially tries to explain every little game concept to you whenever it is relevant. After one or two games, you really don't need it at all.

Low advice is difficult to quantify. Unfortunately, there is no completely correct answer available because the game is very vague on the differences(which is why you are asking), as well as the extremely low chance anyone has tried testing this. The best answer for low advice would be that it tries to only give advice when it comes to the more complex aspects of the game, although in actuality, it is pretty much the same as high advice. Once you don't need high advice on, you probably don't need low advice on either.

You mention that you want a setting that doesn't annoy you with little alerts, only focusing on the important battle aspects like your general dying. That is on no matter what you set your adviser to do. Everything that is said in battle is unrelated to the campaign map adviser. If that is your goal, no advice or low advice both work for that. As far as I know, there is no setting to turn off the battlefield alerts.

Answer (score 0):

No. Even when the advisor is off,he will still tell you if your general dies (unless you have supress advice ticked,which blocks him/her to show up). A high advice level is fit for a begginer,because tells about many things,while a low level makes the advisor to tell just important things.